# Web hosting for websites developed in cake php

Tags: php, web-hosting, cakephp

I have developed my website using Cake PHP. Now, I am looking for a good webhost for my website. Cake PHP requires mod_rewrite to be enabled and also some changes might be required in the document root(apache servers). Moreover, cake php has it's own directory structure.

Are there any web hosts which offer easy deployment for cake php based websites?

My budget is around $10-15 month. But, I can spend a little more for a good web host.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://webhostingtalk.com to get ideas on web hosts. Most webhosts offer PHP and mod_rewrite, many are much cheaper than Slicehost which is a nice VPS but is overkill unless your site needs the overhead.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could be an excellent candidate for a slice from slicehost-you get your own virtual server and you can configure it as you will.

Their 256MB slice comes in at $20/month-which is close to your bottom line. It also gives you a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the document root, you can use symlinks to point into your webroot and set the paths in the webroot/index.php for the core and root. Most hosts have mod rewrite and shell access.

If you're just starting a new account on dreamhost will cover you just fine and they are cheap and have decent support. They are not very fast, but as far as security (different user accounts for each website and restrict them to sftp only) shell access, and customization of your environment (you can run your own php.ini etc) they can't be beat.

Once you outgrow them, you can move over to slicehost or cloudservers (same servers different packages).

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you mean by *easy*. A VPS could be easy to deploy if you know your way around the command line. That will give you full control over everything that you need. You could consider one of the [VPSLink](http://vpslink.com) packages. Fits within your budget.